# How can I change my QListWidget implementation to improve performance?

Tags: performance, qt, pyqt

Understandably, the code below shows that the QList.addItems call takes 0.393 seconds. I am using similar code in a larger program - the idea is the user is presented with a (very) large list of unique part numbers. They begin entering a regular expression in a separate QEntry widget, which updates the QList in real-time, cutting the list shorter and shorter as it goes.

The problem I have is that with such a large list, it takes a noticeable amount of time to update the QList view as the user inputs their regular expression. I do not imagine that this is a unique issue - what are common solutions to this problem? How can I truncate my list in a reasonable manner such that the user experience is not significantly negatively impacted? Is a QListView a better alternative? Does it make sense to cut the list short to, say, 100 items or so and load more items in real-time as the user scrolls? Or are there pitfalls to this approach?

```
import time
from itertools import cycle
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

pns = cycle(['ABCD', 'EFGH', 'IJKL', 'MNOP'])

pn_col = []
for i in range(505000):
    pn_col.append("{}_{}".format(next(pns), i))

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
myList = QtGui.QListWidget()
start = time.clock()
myList.addItems(pn_col)
print("Time = {}".format(time.clock() - start))
```

update : turns out my list is actually about 4000 unique values repeating for the grand total of 500k. doh! cutting out the duplicates fixed my performance issue. I am still interested in knowing, though, for science and stuff, more efficient ways of listing this data. and it is a true flat list, I cannot easily group or hierarchy them.

Comment: What is the purpose of showing them **all** in a flat list? That seems like a truly horrible interface (imagine that your file manager worked that way). The fact that you can use patterns to progressively reduce the size of the list implies that the data can be structured as a tree. And if so, each branch of the tree can be populated on demand, rather than loading everything all at once.

Answer (score 2):

A `QListWidget` is a convenient widget for small lists. To have a real list you should have a `QListView` associated to a `QAbstractListModel` that you reimplement.

In your example, the list is 500k items long! How about using a real database to handle that? With Qt you can the `QSqlTableModel` associated to [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/), see the [doc here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsqltablemodel.html). The sorting and searching will be done in SQL and the results propagated to the model.

Note: if you use python 2.7, replace `range()` by `xrange()`, it returns a value at a time instead of constructing the whole list of 500k elements in memory.